# Does enumitem conflict with beamer for lists?

Tags: beamer, lists, enumitem

I am using the enumitem package in a beamer presentation.
When I added a usepackage directive for it, the bullets in front of itemize lists disappeared.

I tried restoring them by using

```
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\scriptsize\raise1.25pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleright$}}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\tiny\raise1.5pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleright$}}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}{\tiny\raise1.5pt\hbox{\donotcoloroutermaths$\blacktriangleright$}}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{\insertenumlabel.}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subitem}{\insertenumlabel.\insertsubenumlabel}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate subsubitem}{\insertenumlabel.\insertsubenumlabel.\insertsubsubenumlabel}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate mini template}{\insertenumlabel}
```

but that didn't help.

Is there a way to set up bullets in beamer when using the enumitem package? I want to actually set a latex symbol or even an .png image of my own.

Comment: managed to fix it by adding \setlist{label=\blacksquare}

Comment: If you've managed to answer your own question then you should actually _answer_ it!  I mean, put that answer in an answer box below.  That way, anyone else having the same problem will see that your question has been answered and click through to see the answer.  Right now, it _looks_ from the front page as though no one can answer this.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

`enumitem` redefines `beamer` list features. You can combine `enumitem` with `beamer` features and templates. This example demonstrates the use of `\setitemize` (from `enumitem`) with `beamer` templates, restoring font, color and template of the current `beamer` theme:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{label=\usebeamerfont*{itemize item}%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize item}
  \usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item First item
    \item Second item
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

So, with a default `beamer` document, you would get blue triangles also with `enumitem`.

[image: enumitem and beamer demo]

Comment: So in general the trick is to add back in the beamer features you want inside the `\setlist` command?

Comment: @Seamus Yes, that's what I think.

Comment: Thanks - this works even with an overlay alert specification, I think. (I wasn't sure if it would - `beamer`'s template system confuses me!)

Comment: OK. I don't regret (+1)ing this answer, but too bad it fails when I add an `enumerate` environment!

Comment: To fix the 'TeX capacity exceeded' when adding an `enumerate`, I had to redefine the `enumerate` list parameters, e.g. `\setlist[enumerate]{label=\arabic*.}`. This does not take into account the beamer template, however.

Comment: Is there a way to add back [<+->]? When I try to use this option together with enumitem I get an error "Package enumitem Error: <-+> undefined."

Comment: This works, however not when nesting several itemize environments (f.i. the font sizes don't scale correclty)