# beamer: how to increase space between bullet and text in itemize environment?

Tags: beamer, spacing, itemize, beamerposter

I am using

```
\documentclass[final, hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}, xcolor=svgnames, mathserif]{beamer}
```

and

```
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}
```

In an `itemize` environment, for all items the horizontal spacing between bullet and text is too small. I would like to increase it. I've read about the `\labelsep` option and the `enumitem` package. However, I've also read that `enumitem` should not be used in context with `beamer`. Is there a simple solution?

Edit:
A semi-optimal solution I have found so far is in the preamble

```
\usepackage{enumitem}% http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem
\setitemize{label=\usebeamerfont*{itemize item}
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize item}
  \usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}
```

and then using e.g.

```
\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=*,labelindent=1cm,labelsep=0.5cm]
```

This is based on [Does enumitem conflict with beamer for lists?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24371/does-enumitem-conflict-with-beamer-for-lists). For my special case, this is definitely fine. However, beamer-specific formatting of nesting level two is lost (and probably more).

Comment: A MWE would be helpful, but i think i \vspace should work ill check and if it works ill answer

Comment: Related question [Global setting of spacing between items in itemize environment for beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16793/10478)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply change the relevant list length. (It is perhaps also necessary to change in a similar way `\leftmarginii` and `\leftmarginiii`):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
 \begin{itemize}
 \item test
 \item test
 \end{itemize}



\setlength\labelsep   {\dimexpr\labelsep + 0.5em\relax}  
\setlength\leftmargini{\dimexpr\leftmargini + 0.5em\relax}
 \begin{itemize}
 \item test
 \item test
 \end{itemize}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `labelsep` can be used to obtain the desired effect.

```
\documentclass[final, hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}, xcolor=svgnames, mathserif]{beamer}
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{label=\usebeamerfont*{itemize item}%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize item}
  \usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}
  \setlist{leftmargin=*,labelindent=1cm,labelsep=8cm}
\begin{document}


\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item first
\item second
\item third
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

other sizes can be used as well, hope this answers you question

Comment: Thanks, Rick. This is nice. Do you think there also is a proper document-wide solution? I found a hacky one, as indicated in the edit of my question above.

Comment: I assume there is a better solution, I'll edit my answer if i find a better one

Comment: Rick, actually you got me wrong. I am looking for a way to add horizontal space between bullet and text, not vertical space between items!

Comment: ahh then you answered your own question, labelsep does that. Edited my answer, my bad btw I read your question wrong

Comment: My edited answer is less hacky. this changes it for the entire document but might also affects other labels which use the labelsep command.