# Alignment of custom icon in Beamer

Tags: beamer, align, vertical-alignment, mathtools, fontawesome

I am not a Latex expert so while writing my documents, I face many problems with TeX command. And TeX StackExchange provides answers for most of my problems. However, one of my problems still does not have a consistent answer. I would like to share a solution after conducting many searches on Tex StackExchange.

## Problem

When making presentation slides with `Beamer`, sometimes I need to use a custom icon for the item in itemize environment. It's just sometimes so I really don't need to define `\setbeamertemplate{enumerate items}[]` and `\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[]` globally.

My preferred package for custom icon is `fontawesome5`  [CTAN: Package fontawesome5](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome5).

Let's have an example to demonstrate the problem.

```
\begin{frame}{Alginment Test}
\begin{itemize}
    \item[{\faThumbsUp}] Good condition
    \item[{\faMeh[regular]}] Degraded condition
    \item[{\faTimes}] Failure condition
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

(remember to add `\usepackage{fontawesome5}` to your preamble)

will produce:

[image]

As you can see, the icons are not vertically center alignment. In other document classes, we can fix this problem easily using `enumitem` package. A complete workaround for regular classes like `article` or `report` can be found here: [itemize - alignment of custom bullet symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231787/itemize-alignment-of-custom-bullet-symbols). However, we are using the `beamer` class, loading `enumitem` will ruined the beamer's structure.
You can find a partial answer without using `enumitem` here [itemize in beamer - alignment of custom bullets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280568/itemize-in-beamer-alignment-of-custom-bullets)
. But the syntax is quite complex for me.

Answer (score 3):

You can load the `fontawesome5` package with the `fixed` option, then all icons are automatically centered in fixed width boxes.

So just replace

```
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
```

with

```
\usepackage[fixed]{fontawesome5}
```

and then you don't have to change anything in your `{itemize}`.

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

To solve this problem, you will need `mathtools` package [CTAN: Package mathtools](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) and its `\clap` command.
Let's have some observations.

First, put the icon inside `\clap{}`:

```
\begin{frame}{Alginment Test}
\begin{itemize}
    \item[\clap{\faThumbsUp}] Good condition
    \item[\clap{\faMeh[regular]}] Degraded condition
    \item[\clap{\faTimes}] Failure condition
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

It will produce:

[image]

The icons are in vertically centering. But the space between the icons and text is too small. So I try to add a white space after the `\clap{}` command like this:

```
\begin{frame}{Alginment Test}
\begin{itemize}
    \item[\clap{\faThumbsUp} ] Good condition %<----- extra white space after \clap{}
    \item[\clap{{\faMeh[regular]}} ] Degraded condition
    \item[\clap{\faTimes} ] Failure condition
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Then we have:

[image]

It's better, right?

However, I do not want to put extra space after `\clap{}` command, the code does not look beautiful.
I conducted another search session on TeX StackExchange and I found this thread: [beamer: how to increase space between bullet and text in itemize environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63158/beamer-how-to-increase-space-between-bullet-and-text-in-itemize-environment). Now, I add the following line of code to the itemize environment and remove all white space after `\clap{}`:

```
\begin{frame}{Alginment Test}
\begin{itemize}
    \setlength\labelsep{10pt} %<---- new line
    \item[\clap{\faThumbsUp}] Good condition
    \item[\clap{{\faMeh[regular]}}] Degraded condition
    \item[\clap{\faTimes}] Failure condition
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

The final result:

[image]

You can adjust the space `10pt` to any number that fit your need. Also remember to put `\setlength\labelsep{10pt}` inside the itemize environment you wish to adjust the space (in case you have some nested lists). You can define new shorter commands for `\clap{your fontawesome5 icon}` if you want. Since I just sometimes use the custom bullet, the original macros are fine.

Thank you very much for reading and I hope this workaround will be helpful.