# Nested lists consistent vertical spacing with Beamer

Tags: beamer, lists, itemize

[image]

When inserting nested lists inside the `beamer` package the vertical spacing between the items is not equal -- i.e. inconsistent.

What is the reason for this behaviour?

And is there a way to avoid the problem without additional packages, or obscure trickery (e.g. [proposed by *JorgeGT*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130643/nested-itemize-environment-affects-vertical-spacing-of-parent-itemize-environmen/339467#339467))?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{No problem}
\begin{itemize}
   \item MMMMMM
   \item MMMMMM
   \item MMMMMM
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Vertical item distance not consistent}
\begin{itemize}
  \item MMMMMM
  \item MMMMMM
  \item MMMMMM
  \begin{itemize}
    \item MMMMMM
    \begin{itemize}
      \item MMMMMM
      \item MMMMMM
      \item MMMMMM
    \end{itemize}
      \item MMMMMM
      \item MMMMMM
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Solution (kinda?!)}
\begin{itemize}
  \item MMMMMM
  \item MMMMMM
  \item MMMMMM % next blank line seems to kinda solve the problem

  \begin{itemize}
    \item MMMMMM
    \begin{itemize}
      \item MMMMMM
      \item MMMMMM
      \item MMMMMM
    \end{itemize}
      \item MMMMMM
      \item MMMMMM
  \end{itemize}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason of the bug (p.113, beameruserguide.pdf):

> This template [`itemize/enumerate body begin`] is inserted at the  beginning of a first-level itemize or enumerate environment.
> Furthermore, before this template is inserted, the beamer -font and -color `itemize/enumerate body` is used.

So `\itemize` change the color and the **size** of the font before the `\list` macro switches from horizontal mode to vertical mode...

**Workaround**: you can patch `\itemize` and `\enumerate` (in your preamble):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\itemize}{\vskip 0pt}{}{}
\pretocmd{\enumerate}{\vskip 0pt}{}{}
```