# description begins on a new line without indent

Tags: beamer, horizontal-alignment, lists, indentation, description

I am using [this method](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/List_Structures) to write description in a new line in [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer),

[image]

But how can I remove the indent at the new line so it aligns with the `\item[]`?

This is what I have right now.

```
\pdfminorversion=4
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{title}
  \fontsize{8pt}{9}\selectfont
  \begin{columns}
    \centering
    \column{.7\textwidth}
    \vbox to .8\textheight{%
    \begin{figure}
      \centering
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../Fig1}
      \end{subfigure}%\hfill
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../Fig2}
      \end{subfigure}\\\vfill
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../Fig3}
      \end{subfigure}%\hfill
      \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{../Fig4}
      \end{subfigure}%
    \end{figure}
    }%

    \column{.3\textwidth}
    Imperfection in Tx and Rx may cause IQ imbalance and other system error.\\
    \begin{description}[leftmargin=0pt]
    \item[Gain Imbalance] \hfill \\Amplitude is different for I and Q.
    \item[Quadrature Error] \hfill \\Phase between I and Q is not \ang{90}.
    \item[IQ Offset] \hfill \\I and Q are not centered at zero.
    \item[Gain Compression] \hfill \\Distance $d$ between constellation points is power dependent.
    \end{description}

  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One easy way is to set `description width` to be equal to `-\labelsep`; in the following example I made the change local to a frame, but if you move the line

```
\setbeamersize{description width=-\labelsep}
```

the change will be global:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

{
\setbeamersize{description width=-\labelsep}
\begin{frame}
\begin{description}
\item[First]\mbox{}\\ The first item.
\item[Second]\mbox{}\\ The second item.
\item[Third]\mbox{}\\ The third item.
\end{description}
\end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

An with the updated code in the question, there's `\begin{description}[leftmargin=0pt]`, so the string "leftmargin=0pt" is taken as the widest label, overriding the previously defined description width; all that needs to be done is to delete `[leftmargin=0pt]`. Notice also that I replaced `figure` with `center` and `subfigure` with `minipage` (there's really no need for neither the `figure` nor for the `subfigure` environments in `beamer`):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

{
\setbeamersize{description width=-\labelsep}
\begin{frame}{title}
  \fontsize{8pt}{9}\selectfont
  \begin{columns}
    \column{.7\textwidth}
    \vbox to .8\textheight{%
    \begin{center}
      \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
      \end{minipage}%\hfill
      \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
      \end{minipage}\\\vfill
      \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
      \end{minipage}%\hfill
      \begin{minipage}[b]{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
      \end{minipage}%
      \end{center}
    }%

    \column{.3\textwidth}

    Imperfection in Tx and Rx may cause IQ imbalance and other system error.\\
    \begin{description}
    \item[Gain Imbalance] \hfill \\Amplitude is different for I and Q.
    \item[Quadrature Error] \hfill \\Phase between I and Q is not \ang{90}.
    \item[IQ Offset] \hfill \\I and Q are not centered at zero.
    \item[Gain Compression] \hfill \\Distance $d$ between constellation points is power dependent.
    \end{description}

  \end{columns}
\end{frame}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! For some reason it didn't work for me, I've uploaded a screenshot of my slide.

Comment: @LWZ A screenshot in this situation is useless; please provide the code producing that result.

Comment: Sorry, I've uploaded the code now, adding `\setbeamersize{description width=-\labelsep}` before the frame did not make any difference.

Comment: @LWZ of course it didn't since you are using `\begin{description}[leftmargin=0pt]` delete `[leftmargin=0pt]`.

Comment: Yes! Now it worked! Sorry most of time I'm just Googling and copy other's code I found. I don't even know what they mean.

Comment: @LWZ no problem! I added some other modifications to your code in my updated answer; perhaps they can also be useful for you.

Answer (score 3):

if you use the `enumitem` package you are able to adjust every parameter of the lists.

to achieve what you want, you need the `itemindent` and the `leftmargin` parameter

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

   \begin{description}[nosep,itemsep=0pt,leftmargin=0pt]
      \item[Counterfactual Test]\hfill\\
      Kann ein Kaugummi erhalten werden, wenn sich kein Kaugummi im Automaten befindet?
   \end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works, but it changed the color of `\item[]`. I'm using it in beamer so I would like to keep the color.

Comment: @LWZ: I've added the [tag:beamer] to your question, since it seem relevant. Also relevant: [Does `enumitem` conflict with `beamer` for lists?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24371/5764)

Comment: Thank you! Seems like it's better to have another way other than using `enumitem`.

Comment: @LWZ: Well i did not know you're using `beamer`, if anyone wants to add a solution working with `beamer` I'll delete mine