# How to reduce a gap between the enumeration and the context from above it?

Tags: beamer, spacing, lists

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}
```

I have a following code

```
\textbf{Definition 1.1} A {\it{design}} is a pair $(X,\mathcal{A})$ iff:
\begin{enumerate}[label={\it{\arabic*}}.,leftmargin=1cm,itemsep=0ex,parsep=-0.3ex]
\item \;\; $X$ is a set of {\it{points}};
\item \;\; $\mathcal{A}$ is a set of {\it{blocks}}.
\end{enumerate}
```

which can be compiled as

[image].

But as you can see, the gap between the context and enumeration is quite big. I've used `topmargin` but didn't worked. How to reduce a gap between them?

Comment: Adjust `topsep` as well...

Comment: Related: [Does `enumitem` conflict with `beamer` for lists?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24371/5764)

Comment: `enumitem` is not full compatible with `beamer`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have  relevant keys in `enumitem` itself: `nosep` or `noitemsep`. Also, instead of adding horizontal space between label and item body for each item, set `labelsep` in the options. Last, I replaced TeX syntax (`{\it…}`) with LaTeX syntax (`\emph{…}`).

Final advice: you should make your definition a theorem-like environment: formatting (boldface) could be pre-defined and numbering would be automatic, making cross-references easy. Imagine what would happen if you should decide to add a definition in the middle of your document.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Definition 1.1} A \emph{design} is a pair $(X,\mathcal{A})$ iff:
\begin{enumerate}[label=\em \arabic*., labelsep = 0.5em,  leftmargin=1cm, nosep]
\item $X$ is a set of \emph{points};
\item $\mathcal{A}$ is a set of \emph{blocks}.
\end{enumerate}
\vskip4ex

\textbf{Definition 1.1} A \emph{design} is a pair $(X,\mathcal{A})$ iff:
\begin{enumerate}[label=\em \arabic*., labelsep = 0.5em,  leftmargin=1cm, noitemsep]
\item $X$ is a set of \emph{points};
\item $\mathcal{A}$ is a set of \emph{blocks}.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is use of `\vspace{-xxpt}` right before `\item`.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress]{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}


Before:

\textbf{Definition 1.1} A {\it{design}} is a pair $(X,\mathcal{A})$ iff:
\begin{enumerate}[label={\it{\arabic*}}.,leftmargin=1cm,itemsep=0ex,parsep=-0.3ex]
\item \;\; $X$ is a set of {\it{points}};
\item \;\; $\mathcal{A}$ is a set of {\it{blocks}}.
\end{enumerate}

After:

\textbf{Definition 1.1} A {\it{design}} is a pair $(X,\mathcal{A})$ iff:
\begin{enumerate}[label={\it{\arabic*}}.,leftmargin=1cm,itemsep=0ex,parsep=-0.3ex]
\vspace{-5pt}
\item \;\; $X$ is a set of {\it{points}};
\item \;\; $\mathcal{A}$ is a set of {\it{blocks}}.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

\setlist{nolistsep} can reduce a little bit. Probably need to go through the package manual.

Comment: Where is `\set` from? You probably mean `\setlist`?

Comment: Yes, I made a mistake. It should be \setlist{nolistsep}, right after the package usage statement.

Comment: You can [edit your question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/192033/edit) in order to revise it. Click on the `edit` link below your post.