# How do I move my sentences up close the title?

Tags: beamer

I am using Share Latex site to create slides for my presentation.

I have the following codes:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathabx}

\title{}
\author{}
\institute{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\frametitle{} 
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\frametitle{Outline}
\end{center}
\begin{itemize}
\item Introduction
\item Model 1
\item Main Results
\begin{itemize}
\item Graphical Analysis
\end{itemize}
\item Model 2
\item Main Results
\begin{itemize}
\item Graphical Analysis
\item Comparative statics
\end{itemize}
\item Conclusion
\item Appendix 
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{center}
\frametitle{Introduction}
\end{center}

\begin{itemize}
\item Academic dishonesty is a serious issue in many developing countries.
\begin{itemize}
\item Cheating in school is a social norm. 
\item Generally, the professors do not take this issue seriously.
\item Low-level of punishment for the perpetrators.
\end{itemize}
\item The objective is to capture a student's decision to either plagiarize or be honest with two prisoner's dilemma models.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I have this slide:
[image]

How do I move my sentences up and I also want to create spaces between the sentences?

Comment: Don't put your `\frametitle` inside a `center` environment; just use it on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `[t]` option to your frames to align the text to the top of the frame. You can use the [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package to control the spacing of the itemized lists as shown in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16809/32374), but you have to restore the default bullets after you do so, as explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24491/32374). Also, as mentioned in a comment, you should not put the `frametitle` in a `center` environment.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{itemsep=20pt,% Change the item separation here
label=\usebeamerfont*{itemize item}% These lines are necessary to restore the bullets to each item
\usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize item}%
\usebeamertemplate{itemize item}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[t] % Add the [t] option here to top-align the text on the slide.
\frametitle{Introduction}

\begin{itemize}
\item Academic dishonesty is a serious issue in many developing countries.
\begin{itemize}
\item Cheating in school is a social norm. 
\item Generally, the professors do not take this issue seriously.
\item Low-level of punishment for the perpetrators.
\end{itemize}
\item The objective is to capture a student's decision to either plagiarize or be honest with two prisoner's dilemma models.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]