# Use noitemsep and nolistsep, itemize options in beamer

Tags: beamer, enumerate, itemize

I am trying to use the options `noitemsep` and `nolistsep` in beamer. My simple code is

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}[noitemsep, nolistsep]
      \item Item 1
      \item Item 2
      \item Item 3
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

My output is

[image]

and I am given the following error

> ! Use of \beamer@parseitem doesn't match its definition.
>   \beamer@defaultospec ->n
>                           oitemsep, nolistsep l.9   \end{frame

}

Any idea how to make those options work in beamer?

Comment: as pointed out in the [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/287027/4686) below you are not even loading package `enumitem` which is the package providing these options.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems to be a general theme from [Does enumitem conflict with beamer for lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24371/does-enumitem-conflict-with-beamer-for-lists/24491#24491) that you need to use `\setlist` to get [beamer](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) and [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) to play well together. In this case,

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep, nolistsep}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Item 1
      \item Item 2
      \item Item 3
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

seems to do what you want:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This really solved it! what if I just want to do it locally and not globally?

Comment: @Thanos Sadly, I can't see a local way to do this...

Answer (score 6):

What about this code for local way?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}[noitemsep,nolistsep]
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2
  \item Item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's a way to do it locally without using the package `enumitem`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2
  \item Item 3
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/3275668/2901422