# Enumitem and Enumerate incompatibility

Tags: enumerate, enumitem

I am loading both `enumerate` and `enumitem` packages on my `beamer` preamble:

```
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\setitemize{label=\usebeamerfont*{itemize item}%
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize item}
  \usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}
\setlength{\leftmargini}{0pt}
\setlength{\leftmarginii}{25pt}
```

Then I am trying to create a nested list combining both `itemize` and `enumerate`:

```
\begin{enumerate}

\item<1->{Some Text}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<2-> Some Text
        \item<2-> Some Text           
    \end{itemize}
\item<3->{Some Text}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item<4-> Some Text
        \item<4-> Some Text
    \end{itemize}

\end{enumerate}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
tex capacity exceeded sorry grouping levels=255
```

Are the two packages incompatible?

Thank you.

Comment: You should load neither `enumerate` nor `enumitem` with `beamer`; in any case, the two packages should never be loaded together.

Comment: Aside from not mixing [`enumerate`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumerate) with [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem), the latter is not compatible with [`beamer`](http://ctan.org/pkg/beamer). See [Does `enumitem` conflict with `beamer` for lists?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/24371/5764)

Comment: Well, the reason why I loaded enumitem was because I wanted to reduce the itemize environment margin which I accomplished by making:
\setlength{\leftmargini}{0pt}
\setlength{\leftmarginii}{25pt}

Is there any other workaround besides enumitem then?

Comment: @volcompt: As far as I can see you're not using any feature from `enumitem` apart from `shortlabels`. `\setlength{\leftmargini}{0pt}` can be done without `enumitem` actually

Comment: Indeed, the whole point of **enumitem** is so that you don't *have* to write things like that. If you are going to write things like that, it is better not to load the package regardless of whether you are using Beamer.

Comment: So if I want custom enumerated items in Beamer, what do I do?

Comment: @SheridanGrant Add `\setenumerate` explicitly somewhere at the beginning of the document, for example: `\setenumerate{label=\arabic*.,itemsep=3pt,topsep=3pt}`.