# Itemize Bullets Don't Show Up

Tags: beamer, itemize, enumitem

As the title says, I don't get pointy triangle bullet lists.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning, shapes.symbols}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}

%\usepackage{gensymb}
%\usepackage{siunitx}

%\sisetup {
    %locale = DE,
    %per-mode = symbol
%}

% THEME AND COLOR SETUP
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme[RGB={205,0,0}]{structure}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[triangle]
\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[square]

\newcommand{\quoted}[1]{
    \glqq#1\grqq
}
\date{27. June 2018}

\mode<presentation>{}

\begin{document}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty


\title{I'm not yet getting the hang of this}
\author{Narusan}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Blabla}
            \begin{itemize} 
                    \item {\color{black}{no bullet point}}
                     \item here neither                     
            \end{itemize}   
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't understand why, it used to work before in other presentations and I haven't really touched anything (I probably did, but nothing I'm aware of).

Comment: Simple answer: Do not load enumitem!

Comment: @TeXnician But I need it for multiple reasons. Any way to get them with enumitem?

Comment: But it will mess up beamer code, because the two are incompatible with each other.

Comment: @TeXnician Guess I'm having [an XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/353950). My workaround was to use enumitem...

Comment: @Narusan If your tex distribution is reasonable up-to-date, you don't need etoolbox

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution to your problem is not to load `enumitem`, because it's incompatible with beamer (see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31524) and if you really want to risk it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24491)).

Some further comments on your code:

- `inputenc` with `utf8` is no longer needed (April 2018's LaTeX format defaults to it)
- you do not need to load `etoolbox` with `beamer` (it's loaded by default)
- instead of your grouping around the `\color` use `\textcolor`, which even uses the grouped text you already have as argument

[image: bullets]

Code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{svg}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, positioning, shapes.symbols}

% THEME AND COLOR SETUP
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme[RGB={205,0,0}]{structure}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[triangle]
\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[square]

\newcommand{\quoted}[1]{
    \glqq#1\grqq
}
\date{27. June 2018}

\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty
\begin{document}  

    \title{I'm not yet getting the hang of this}
    \author{Narusan}

    \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Blabla}
    \begin{itemize} 
        \item \textcolor{black}{no bullet point}
        \item here neither                     
    \end{itemize}   
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

If you really can't do without use the following (from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/24491)), but it will not remove all incompatibilities:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setitemize{label=\usebeamerfont*{itemize item}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize item}
    \usebeamertemplate{itemize item}}
```